# Broken Image icon removal

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Im trying to get rid of the broken image icon. I found a solution that works on chrome and firefox. When i open the page in IE nothing happens.

Can anybody help me? Here is a jsfiddle.

```
img {  position: relative; }
/* style this to fit your needs */
/* and remove [alt] to apply to all images*/
img:after {  
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #999;
  content: attr(alt);
} 
<img src="broken" alt="A broken image">`
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nLsv2yh1/7/

Comment: what is IE ? ...

Comment: Just don't have a broken image?

Comment: @NanditaAroraSharma I know ;) but my question has another meaning ...

Comment: Sorry i didnt get your another meaning :p